# Parâmetros de configuração Android

Tags: android, parâmetros, configuração

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de pegar os valores direto das configurações do android exemplo quero saber se o "Fontes Desconhecidas" esta habilitado, "Modo Desenvolvedor" esta habilitado,"Idioma" ,"Nível do brilho".....

Answer (score 2):

É possível obter essas informações recorrendo à classe [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

Algumas das constantes estão obsoletas por isso, em função da *target api* que pretende utilizar, considere usar, para o mesmo propósito, as classes [Settings.Global](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html) e [Settings.Secure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)

Por exemplo para obter o valor do "nivel de brilho" pré-definido use:

```
try {
    float curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
    getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Fonte do código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562866/2556111)

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia chamar as configurações do Android, através de um botão, dessa maneira:

Botão em XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_config"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_prox"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_prox"
        android:text="@string/btn_config"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:onClick="config" />
```

Veja acima que o atributo `android:onClick` irá chamar o método `config` em sua `MainActivity`, como visto abaixo:

```
package com.newthread;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void config(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

A chamada das configurações é feita através do Intent e da classe `Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS`.

Veja a documentação do Android Developers: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html